# While running function in flutter, the Error: Method not found: 'setState' is found

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am learning Flutter from Angela Yu's Udemy course. There in module 7, we are making a dice generator app. So, on clicking either of the two die, the dice is rolled. So, for the number to be generated, we are calling a function but that is where am facing the issue.

Upon trying to simple run a function, that I am calling from the onpressed command inside stateful class. But, the function is showing me error regarding the setState widget.

Let's say, I call the function from inside of the setState in Stateful widget, the function then doesn't update the values.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text('Dicee'),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red[900],
        ),
        body: DicePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

//class DicePage extends StatelessWidget {}

class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DicePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  int dicenumL = 1;
  int dicenumR = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //var leftdice = 2;
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  pressedDice();
                });
              }, //onPressed
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$dicenumL.png'),
            ),
          ),
          //SizedBox(width: 5.0),
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: (){
                pressedDice();
              }, //onPressed
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$dicenumR.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void pressedDice() {
  setState(() {
    int dicenumL;
    int dicenumR;
    dicenumL = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
    dicenumR = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
  });
}
```

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your function is not in the `Stateful` widget `DicePage` hence the error "`setState` is not found". You can only use `setState` inside `Stateful` widgets

Secondly you have used 2 `setState`'s one in `onPressed` and other inside the `pressedDice` function, do this instead

Remove `setState` from `pressedDice` function

```dart
void pressedDice() {
  int dicenumL;
  int dicenumR;
  dicenumL = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
  dicenumR = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
}
```

Now, I have not tested your code but I don't think your code will work properly after this because you have re-defined `dicenumL` and `dicenumR` in your `pressedDice` function and hence the UI won't be updated even after `setState` call.

So, I suggest move your `pressedDice` function inside the `Stateful` widget and remove those definitions.

```dart
class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DicePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  int dicenumL = 1;
  int dicenumR = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    void pressedDice() {
      setState(() {
        dicenumL = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
        dicenumR = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
      });
    }

    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: (){
                pressedDice();
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$dicenumL.png'),
            ),
          ),
          //SizedBox(width: 5.0),
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: (){
                pressedDice();
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$dicenumR.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is very simple move the method pressedDice() inside of the _DicePageState class()

> we can get access to setState method only in _DicePageState class but
> you have tried to access it outside of the class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text('Dicee'),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red[900],
        ),
        body: DicePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

//class DicePage extends StatelessWidget {}

class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DicePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  int dicenumL = 1;
  int dicenumR = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //var leftdice = 2;
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  pressedDice();
                });
              }, //onPressed
              child: Image.asset('asset/dice.png'),
            ),
          ),
          //SizedBox(width: 5.0),
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                pressedDice();
              }, //onPressed
              child: Image.asset('asset/dice.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void pressedDice() {
    setState(() {
      int dicenumL;
      int dicenumR;
      dicenumL = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
      dicenumR = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
      print(dicenumR);
      print('the dice value in the left dice $dicenumL');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s not working because you use the new int value inside the function and set build method's value to set it

Like:

In build class you assign the
int dicenumL = 1;
int dicenumR = 1;

And inside the function, you declare a new int value
int dicenumL;
Int dicenumR;

So, remove the new int from the function and move the function inside the state class it will work

**Here is code for your solution**

```
class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DicePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  int dicenumL = 1;
  int dicenumR = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  pressedDice();
                });
              }, //onPressed
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$dicenumL.png'),
            ),
          ),
          //SizedBox(width: 5.0),
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                pressedDice();
              }, //onPressed
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$dicenumR.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void pressedDice() {
    setState(() {
      dicenumL = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
      dicenumR = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
    });
  }
}
```